# Microsoft SCCM (Build 1606) - Software Update Group console data out of date

Tags: sccm

How can I go about troubleshooting the root cause (assuming this is unexpected behavior), or manually updating the compliance information for the Software Library->Overview->Software Updates->All Software Updates->MY SOFTWARE UPDATE GROUP NAME console data? I deployed a handful of software updates, and the compliance shows 100% for the various deployments under Monitoring->Overview->Deployments->MY DEPLOYMENT NAME, but not under the Software Library view. There is a single update in the Software Library view which has significantly out of date data, it says its last update time was more than 7 hours ago. The last update time for the other 3 software updates in the software update group is relatively recent. I've tried clicking the Run Summarization button, but it has had no effect.

**Edit**

Aproximately 12 hours later, the Software Update Group finally has been updated. So I guess my question could be narrowed down to, how can I force this data to be updated since Run Summarization doesn't seem to work here as it does on the Deployment screens. Is there a stored procedure or something?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the update compliance report time depends on the Client Policy polling interval specified in the Client Settings (the default value is 60 mins). However, you can force your clients to execute the Software Update compliance scan & deployment evaluation by using the Right-Click tools justt like below:

[image]

After the compliance scan is complete, you can click "Run Summarization" option which will force your clients to send the compliance status to your site server/site database, then you will see the data update on the Software Update Group dashboard.